# I want to have a consistent column width

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

So I have a table and within each cell, is a gridview. Basically it's tables within a table. Right now, the columns in each gridview have arbitrary widths, depending on the length of each text in each cell. I want to make them all the same so it's nicer to look at.

In a loop, I make each gridview, bind to a cell, bind to a row, and appending to the outer table. I tried to add this statement after I bound the gridview to a dataview to make the first columns consistent in width:

```
gvTemp.Columns[0].ItemStyle.Width = Unit.Pixel(400);
```

But I get an error saying that 0 was too big of an index, even though the gridview is not empty.

Am I using the wrong methods? Am I placing the code in an incorrect location?

Answer (score 0):

One way to sort out this issue is the use percentages in CSS combined with a bit of simple maths in javascript. Use javascript to obtain the number of  columns in your table, divide by 100 and apply that result as a width value in percent to each column. This way, no matter how many or how few columns you have it will always evenly split them.

It become a problem when you have many columns and they become too narrow to be used plausibly, in which case you would be better setting a width in pixels for each column.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the Columns property is for explicitly declared columns where yours are probably implicit from the datasource.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.columns(v=vs.110).aspx

Check the Rows property. You might have to set the width of cells within the first row:

```
Rows[0].Cells[0].Width = Unit.Pixel(400)
```